# Simple recursive function in VBA with Excel not returning expected result

Tags: excel, vba, recursion

I have a simple recursive function to write in VBA that does the following : It must count the number of times we must take the log of a parameter 'x' to find log(x) < 1

Examples :

- logcount(5) : log(5) = 0,6... so the function should return 1
- logcount(89) : log(89) = 1,9... and log(log(89)) = 0,28... so the function should return 2
- logcount(0,4) should return 1
  etc...

So I wrote it and it doesn't work as expected ! It always adds +1 to the result ! It looks like the last 'Else' block is always interpreted. Any help will be really appreciated

```
Function logcount(x As Double) As Integer
  If x <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a positive value"
    Exit Function
  ElseIf Log(x) < 1 Then
    logcount = 1
  Else
    logcount = 1 + logcount(Log(x))
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: what is `logcount(0,4)` Your function only takes one parameter. Also as written `logcount(1)` and `logcount(2)` both return 1

Comment: @ConradFrix `0,4` is `0.4` written in a non-Englis-US locale (which is used through the question), where the decimal point is `,`.

Comment: Sorry, in france we put a comma as a decimal separator, you should read '0.4'

Comment: @YassT no my apologies. I actually know better and I still got caught by my Anglo/US centric view of the decimal mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Log` in VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251336%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is the natural logarithm.

Apparently you meant a base-10 logarithm:

```
Log10 = Log(X) / Log(10#)
```

Comment: OMG ! In fact I was checking my results with using the log in the windows calc ! So with this calc, we have the base-10 log, right ? My program was correct if I want the natural log ?