# Logarithm is different using VBA and Excel function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get the log of a number but it looks like the Worksheet function gives one answer, and VBA another.

In VB, using `Log(Range("A2"))` where A2 is 7, I get `1.94591014905531`, which is the correct answer.  But, if in the worksheet, I use `=Log(A2,10)` or `=Log10(a2)`, I get `0.84509804`.  What's going on here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple recursive function in VBA with Excel not returning expected result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071559/simple-recursive-function-in-vba-with-excel-not-returning-expected-result)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

VBA's `Log` function is the natural log. If you want log base ten you will have to use the logarithmic identity for converting bases. Like so: `Log(x)/Log(10)`.

Comment: Also, that you refer to 1.94593... as the *correct answer* implies that it is indeed the natural log you are looking for? To do this in a formula, use =LOG(A2,EXP(1)). Here, EXP(1) gives us e^1 = e = 2.72...., the base of the natural log.

Comment: You can also use Excel's version with `Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function roundit1(nn As Variant, sd As Variant)
    nn = Val(nn)
    If Not (nn = 0) Then
        xx = (1 + Int(Log(Abs(nn)) / Log(10)))
    Else
        xx = 0
    End If
    ' significant digits
    roundit = sd - xx
    If roundit < 0 Then roundit = 0
   roundit1 = Round(nn, roundit)
End Function
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.