# vba Fix function, double comparisons returning unexpected value

Tags: excel, vba

Fix function in vba is returning 2 when 3 is passed:

```
Debug.Print (Fix(Log(1000) / Log(10)))
```

--> This prints 2 instead of 3

Why is that?

Comment: Hmm - plugged that in to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fix%28log%281000%29%2Flog%2810%29%29), and the result is "3", but look at the numberline visual, it's "2"...I wonder if that is what Excel's getting too?

Comment: I don't understand your request to look at the numberline visual.

Comment: It probably doesn't help get to an answer, but if you click the link, do you not see a numberline?  Also, `int(log(1000)/log(10))` is giving `2` as well. Odd.  Why do you want to use `Fix()`?

Answer (score 2):

`Log(1000)/Log(10)` or 6.90775527898214 ÷ 2.30258509299405 should be equal to **3** but it appears that the 15 digit floating point precision is generating a [15 digit precision floating point error](http://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers) and Fix is trucating off all of the decimal. If you [Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242034(v=vs.60).aspx) to 15 decimal places to remove the infinitesimally small error, you will receive **3** as your answer.

```
?round(log(1000)/log(10), 15)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Debug.Print Log(1000)   '6.90775527898214
Debug.Print Log(10)     '2.30258509299405

6.90775527898214
   /
2.30258509299405
=2.999999999999996      'VBA is convering this to '3#'

Debug.Print Fix(3#)     '2
Debug.Print Round(Fix(Log(1000) / Log(10)))     '2
Debug.Print Round(Round(Fix(Log(1000)) / Round(Log(10))))   '3 (This is what you want)  
Debug.Print (Round(Fix(Log(1000)) / Round(Log(10))))        '3 (Or may be only this)
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing a debug on the Log function:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim number As Double
    number = Log(1000)
    Debug.Print number
End Sub
```

prints: 6.90775527898214

And

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim number As Double
    number = Log(10)
    Debug.Print number
End Sub
```

prints: 2.30258509299405

when you divide those you get: 2.(a lot of 9's) and calling Fix on that number will give you 2 not 3.

Answer (score 0):

Hm - I think this is how VB handles Log vs how the worksheet function handles it.  Using this, I get `3`:

`Debug.Print fix(worksheetfunction.log10(1000)/worksheetfunction.log10(10))`

I remembered I had a similar issue with Logs, and asked about it on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618472/logarithm-is-different-using-vba-and-excel-function), so perhaps it's a related issue here.

Answer (score 0):

> When you work with floating-point numbers (Single Data Type (Visual
>   Basic) and Double Data Type (Visual Basic)), remember that they are
>   stored as binary fractions. This means they cannot hold an exact
>   representation of any quantity that is not a binary fraction (of the
>   form k / (2 ^ n) where k and n are integers). For example, 0.5 (= 1/2)
>   and 0.3125 (= 5/16) can be held as precise values, whereas 0.2 (= 1/5)
>   and 0.3 (= 3/10) can be only approximations.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae382yt8.aspx

So what I did is created another fix function which looks like this:
'fix has issues with

```
Public Function FixModified(ByVal x As Double, ByVal threshold As Double)
    If Fix(x) = x Then
        FixModified = x
    ElseIf Fix(x) + 1 - x < threshold Then
        FixModified = Fix(x) + 1
    Else
        FixModified = Fix(x)
    End If
End Function
```

The threshold I am passing now is 0.000000000001 and it is working as expected.