# Fix operator problems in VB6

Tags: vb6

All,
I'm intermediate for VB6. I want to get remainder from divided two doubles. I used ,

```
Dim a As Double, b As Double, result As Double
b = 8333.33
a = 58333.31

result = a - (b * Fix(a / b))
```

result should be 0. But it is not.
a/b =7 and no remain. So Fix(a / b) should be 7. But Fix(a / b)=6, Why?

Comment: Because you're dealing with floating point numbers. [Here's your explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/troubleshooting-data-types). In short: while the result of 58333.31 / 8333.33 appears to be 7, internally it's not, but 6.SomethingVeryCloseTo7, which in turn is (correctly) rounded down to the nearest lower integer number = 6. See also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359441/vba-fix-function-double-comparisons-returning-unexpected-value)

Comment: It is better to think of `Fix( )` as "truncating toward 0" then "rounding down."  As opposed to `Int( )` for example.  You must consider negative values to see the distinction.

Comment: The built-in function Round(expression [,numdecimalplaces]) may be of some help here, but you must still consider that many (most) fractional decimal numbers can't be represented exactly in binary floating point, regardless of the precision.

Answer (score 3):

BTW, another trick to get it working - depending on the floating point numbers you need to work with - is to use `Currency` instead of `Double`

```
Dim a As Currency, b As Currency

b = 8333.33
a = 58333.31

Debug.Print Fix(a / b) ' Returns 7
Debug.Print a - (b * Fix(a / b)) ' Returns 0
```

Comment: It is a better solution,It solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you use this as a workaround I think you will get the result you expect:

```
Dim a As Double, b As Double, intermediate As Double, fixed1 As Double, fixed2 As Double

b = 8333.33
a = 58333.31

intermediate = a / b
fixed1 = Fix(intermediate)
fixed2 = Fix(a / b)

Debug.Print intermediate ' 7
Debug.Print fixed1       ' 7
Debug.Print fixed2       ' 6
```

[Documentation for `Fix` says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions):

> **Int, Fix functions**
>
> Returns the integer portion of a number.
>
> ... Remarks Both Int and Fix remove the fractional part of number and
> return the resulting integer value.

(that is from VBA docs but should be the same for VB6).

Apparently when VB evaluates `a / b` within the context of the function call it results in a floating point value very slightly < 7.