# Calculating logarithm own base in Basic (LibreOffice Calc Macro)

Tags: libreoffice, basic, libreoffice-basic

LibreOffice has function `LOG(x;n)` where you can define your own base.

However, when I use Macro to write function in Basic, It does not take second parameter into account thus calculating natural logarithm.
How to calculate logarithm with own base in Basic language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple formula to calculate with any base using the natural log.  The function `LogBase` was taken from Andrew Pitonyak's [OpenOffice.org Macros Explained](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=1930919514) page 79.

```vb
Sub MyLogarithm
    MsgBox(LogBase(256,4))
End Sub

Function LogBase(x, b) As Double
    LogBase = Log(x) / Log(b)
End Function
```

Excel and VBA also do this: [Logarithm is different using VBA and Excel function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618472/logarithm-is-different-using-vba-and-excel-function).