# Difference in Macro vs Manual Output on same formula using LOG

Tags: excel, excel-formula, derivative, vba

Well its rather a very strange  question

I have a macro which generates the delta of a Option(d1):

```
Function dOne(UnderlyingPrice, ExercisePrice, Time, Interest, Volatility, Dividend)

    dOne = (Log(UnderlyingPrice / ExercisePrice) + (Interest - Dividend + (0.5 * Volatility ^ 2)) * Time) / (Volatility * (Sqr(Time)))

End Function
```

When I pass the the values to it, it generates the desired output:

[image: Delta value using macro]

However when I try to replicate this in Excel, it gives an entirely different output

[image: Delta when values are passed manually]

I know that the calculations for output generated manually are correct. 
However the desired values are those generated from VBA.

Please suggest what am I missing here.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618472/logarithm-is-different-using-vba-and-excel-function).

Comment: If "the desired values are those generated from VBA." then the exact equivalent as Excel formula will be `=(LN(E1/E2)+(E4-E6+(0.5*E5^2))*E3)/(E5*(SQRT(E3)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Log` function in VBA is the natural log: **ln(x)**.
The `LOG` function in the formula is log base 10: **log<sub>10</sub>(x)**.

If you want log base 10 in VBA you will have to use the logarithmic identity for converting bases:

```
Log(x)/Log(10)
```

In your case

```
dOne = (Log(UnderlyingPrice / ExercisePrice) / Log(10) + (Interest - Dividend + (0.5 * Volatility ^ 2)) * Time) / (Volatility * (Sqr(Time)))
```