# excel vba | change absolute cells in loop

Tags: vba, excel

Hiyall!

How to change formula absolute cells in loop?
Lets say I have link `=ref!$C$2*4`, how to move in 1 row lower for next run in the loop `=ref!$C$3*4`? Do I need to split it and add counter? Or there is an easier way?

sample code

```
Dim cycle As Range
For Each cycle In Sheets("ref").Range("A2:A4")
    ...
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ref!R2C2" + "*4"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D3")
    ...
End Sub
```

Also I am curious how to add math formulas in VBA like =(С4+B4)/LOG10(A4) + 12, using quote marks did not help at all :<

Comment: Concerning the log math formulas - `Debug.Print Math.Log(10)` Or even better - check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31618564/5448626

Answer (score 1):

Use ***Formula*** rather than ***FormulaR1C1***

```
Sub dural()
    With Range("D2")
        .Formula = "=(C4+B4)/LOG10(A4) + 12"
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D3")
    End With
End Sub
```

Note the arguments will auto-adjust in the fill-down:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! And how do I change in formula C4, B4 and A4 to  row below them in followin run? @garys-student

Comment: @J  See the picture in the answer...........the formula automatically adjusts during the fill-down process.

Comment: @garys-student my bad, I wanted to apply it to my example w/ absolute cell =ref!$C$2*4 or better this one =($С$4+$B$4)/LOG10($A$4) + 12. As it can be seen from the beginning 
`For Each cycle In Sheets("ref").Range("A2:A4")`
there are 3 values in cycle so there will be 3 runs. What I what to do is to for each run automatically move absolute cells a row down or column left or wherever.