# VBA logarithm of any base

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am wondering if there is a way of getting the logarithm of a value for any base.

Specifically I want to get the value of any integer on the base 11.5.

In Excel I have this formula:

```
=LOG(A1,11.5)
```

However as this link: [Logarithm is different using VBA and Excel function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618472/logarithm-is-different-using-vba-and-excel-function) and many others state that the worksheet function is different from the VBA statement.

Is there a way to actually get the base 11.5 logarithm of any integer in VBA?

Comment: It's [just math](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9071658/11683).

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot apply the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) or [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) to use the native worksheet function? e.g. `dim x as double: x = worksheetfunction.log(sheet1.cells(1,1), 11.5)`

Comment: Yes, my tagging is off. I am using Word VBA in fact.

Comment: Then create an excel.application object. VBA works across all office applications but you have to create an application object in order to use the native functions. If you can change a word document from excel then you can use excel's native worksheet functions in word.

Comment: +1 for @GSerg I should have pay attention in class... This gave me the answer... https://www.google.com/#q=converting+log+10+to+any+base

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my maths textbook:

> log<sub>*b*</sub> *x* = log<sub>*c*</sub> *x* / log<sub>*c*</sub> *b*

Therefore in VBA:

```
Log(x) / Log(11.5)
```

will give you the base 11.5 logarithm of `x`, and it doesn't actually matter what the base of VBA's `Log` function is (although as your link states, it's actually the natural log i.e. base *e*)

Comment: Was a valid question though... for those of us have not so carefully studied our math textbook...

Comment: Just for a finishing touch, see my posted answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of nekomantic and the comments, this is an extension method to extend the VBA functionality with Log on any base:

```
Function Logn(base As Double, x As Long)

    Logn = Log(x) / Log(base)

End Function
```